# hdbscan Parallel Error When Running After Import

Tags: python, pandas, scope, joblib

I am building and fitting an hdbscan model on my data and when I run the script from within the file it works well and quickly, but when I import the file and run it from 'outside' it goes into a weird loop that I don't understand how it started.  And I get the following error:

```
ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using "if __name__ == '__main__'". Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information
```

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
df_pos_raw, df_pos_training = pre_process_data(df_pos)
df_pos_training_std = standardize_df(df_pos_training)  # Standardized data, column-wise
print "generating model"
pos_cls = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=10, prediction_data=True)
print "fitting model to data"
pos_cls.fit(df_pos_training_std)
print 'done fitting model'
# sns.distplot(pos_cls.labels_, bins=len(set(pos_cls.labels_)))
df_filtered = filter_cons_types(df, [3, 5])
print "Done. returning variables"
return pos_cls, df_filtered
```

Here is the output when running from 'outside' the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
generating model
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
fitting model to data
prepare(preparation_data)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 510, in prepare
'__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\DataImputation\ClusteringExtrapolation\Dev\run_clustering_based_prediction.py", line 4, in <module>
model, raw_df = clustering()
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\DataImputation\ClusteringExtrapolation\Dev\clustering_model_constype_3_5.py", line 86, in main
pos_cls.fit(df_pos_training_std)
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\venv\lib\site-packages\hdbscan\hdbscan_.py", line 816, in fit
self._min_spanning_tree) = hdbscan(X, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\venv\lib\site-packages\hdbscan\hdbscan_.py", line 543, in hdbscan
core_dist_n_jobs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 362, in __call__
return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\venv\lib\site-packages\hdbscan\hdbscan_.py", line 239, in _hdbscan_boruvka_kdtree
n_jobs=core_dist_n_jobs, **kwargs)
File "hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx", line 375, in hdbscan._hdbscan_boruvka.KDTreeBoruvkaAlgorithm.__init__ (hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.c:5195)
File "hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx", line 411, in hdbscan._hdbscan_boruvka.KDTreeBoruvkaAlgorithm._compute_bounds (hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.c:5915)
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 749, in __call__
n_jobs = self._initialize_backend()
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 547, in _initialize_backend
**self._backend_args)
File "C:\Users\sareetn\PycharmProjects\Arad\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 305, in configure
'[joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing '
ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using "if __name__ == '__main__'". Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information
generating model
fitting model to data
generating model
fitting model to data
generating model
fitting model to data
```

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me figure it out-

Clustering uses a library called joblib that splits the job into parallel processes.  When running such functions on a Windows machine, care needs to be taken to make sure we use

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

in order to protect the code and allow the parallel processing to work.
After adding

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

and placing all of the code there, the clustering ran smoothly and quickly